# Android: Keep username logged in even after I close the application

Tags: android, session, authentication, registration

I'm new to Android and I'm doing an application that has 3 screens:

1. first screen with sign in and sign up buttons;
2. a registration screen;
3. my main screen with the functionalities of the app.

The registration and login are working just fine, the problem is that I need to find a way to keep the application logged in even though I closed the application.

This is the home screen activity (the login screen appears as a popup in this screen):

```
    public class HomeActivity extends Activity
    {
        Button btnSignIn,btnSignUp;
        LoginDataBaseAdapter loginDataBaseAdapter;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.main);

            // create a instance of SQLite Database
            loginDataBaseAdapter=new LoginDataBaseAdapter(this);
            loginDataBaseAdapter=loginDataBaseAdapter.open();

            // Get The Refference Of Buttons
            btnSignIn=(Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonSignIN);
            btnSignUp=(Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonSignUP);

            // Set OnClick Listener on SignUp button
            btnSignUp.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                    /// Create Intent for SignUpActivity  abd Start The Activity
                    Intent intentSignUP=new Intent(getApplicationContext(),SignUPActivity.class);
                    startActivity(intentSignUP);
                }
            });
        }
        // Methos to handleClick Event of Sign In Button
        public void signIn(View V)
        {
            final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(HomeActivity.this);
            dialog.setContentView(R.layout.login);
            dialog.setTitle("Login");

            // get the Refferences of views
            final  EditText editTextUserName=(EditText)dialog.findViewById(R.id.editTextUserNameToLogin);
            final  EditText editTextPassword=(EditText)dialog.findViewById(R.id.editTextPasswordToLogin);

            Button btnSignIn=(Button)dialog.findViewById(R.id.buttonSignIn);

            // Set On ClickListener
            btnSignIn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // get The User name and Password
                    String userName=editTextUserName.getText().toString();
                    String password=editTextPassword.getText().toString();

                    // fetch the Password form database for respective user name
                    String storedPassword=loginDataBaseAdapter.getSinlgeEntry(userName);

                    // check if the Stored password matches with  Password entered by user
                    if(password.equals(storedPassword))
                    {
                        Toast.makeText(HomeActivity.this, "Congrats: Login Successfull", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        dialog.dismiss();

                        //SharedPreferences 

                        SharedPreferences sharedPref = getActivity().getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPref.edit();
                        editor.putInt(getString(userName), new_login);
                        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPref.edit();
                        editor.putInt(getString(password), new_password);

                        editor.commit();

                        //Teste pra mandar o usuario

                        Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), wheel.class);
                        i.putExtra("new_variable_name",userName);

                        //Teste pra mandar o usuario

                        Intent browserIntent =
                                new Intent(HomeActivity.this, wheel.class);

                        startActivity(browserIntent);
                        startActivity(i);

                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Toast.makeText(HomeActivity.this, "User Name or Password does not match", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                }
            });

            dialog.show();
        }

        @Override
        protected void onDestroy() {
            super.onDestroy();
            // Close The Database
            loginDataBaseAdapter.close();
        }
     }
```

This is my registration activity:

```
public class SignUPActivity extends Activity
{
    EditText editTextUserName,editTextPassword,editTextConfirmPassword;
    Button btnCreateAccount, btn_home;

    LoginDataBaseAdapter loginDataBaseAdapter;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.signup);

        // get Instance  of Database Adapter
        loginDataBaseAdapter=new LoginDataBaseAdapter(this);
        loginDataBaseAdapter=loginDataBaseAdapter.open();

        // Get Refferences of Views
        editTextUserName=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editTextUserName);
        editTextPassword=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editTextPassword);
        editTextConfirmPassword=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editTextConfirmPassword);

        btn_home=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_home);
        btn_home.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            public void onClick(View v){
                Intent browserIntent =
                        new Intent(SignUPActivity.this, HomeActivity.class);
                startActivity(browserIntent);
            }
        });

        btnCreateAccount=(Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonCreateAccount);
        btnCreateAccount.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                String userName=editTextUserName.getText().toString();
                String password=editTextPassword.getText().toString();
                String confirmPassword=editTextConfirmPassword.getText().toString();

                // check if any of the fields are vaccant
                if(userName.equals("")||password.equals("")||confirmPassword.equals(""))
                {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Field Vaccant", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    return;
                }
                // check if both password matches
                if(!password.equals(confirmPassword))
                {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Password does not match", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    return;
                }
                else
                {
                    // Save the Data in Database
                    loginDataBaseAdapter.insertEntry(userName, password);
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Account Successfully Created ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }
        });

    }
    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onDestroy();

        loginDataBaseAdapter.close();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Save the authentication data in [SharedPreferences](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html). And check it whenever the app opens, if the user is logged in or not.

Edit 1:

Here is how you will [write data to SharedPreferences](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/shared-preferences.html#WriteSharedPreference).

And to [read data from SharedPreferences](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/shared-preferences.html#ReadSharedPreference).

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Do I need to create another activity in order to use this SharedPreferences?

Comment: No, you don't need to.

Comment: Do you have any example code using this? Because I can seem to understand it very well.

Comment: I Just added examples to read and write data into sharedprefs.

Comment: Thank you! I just added the piece of code in the "public void SignIn" right after the "//SharedPreferences" comment line. Was that correct?

Comment: SharedPref is a key value set. http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/shared-preferences.html

Answer (score 0):

I think this might help you: http://codeasp.net/blogs/android/1662/shared-preferences-in-android-applications

Even if you close the application on pressing the "LOAD DATA" button you will be able to fetch the saved login details.